# Wrapping MUI with my library returns error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-hooks, material-ui

I want to build a library that wraps MUI.
I created a Button with this code:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

import './Button.css'

export interface ButtonProps {
    color: "inherit" | "primary" | "secondary" | "success" | "error" | "info" | "warning" | undefined;
    children: ReactNode;
    size: "small" | "medium" | "large" | undefined;
    variant: "text" | "contained" | "outlined" | undefined;
}

const IButton = (props: ButtonProps) => {
    console.log(props)
    return <Button {...props}>{props.children}</Button>
}

export default IButton
```

This code is working in storybook but when I import it in my App project, I am getting this error:
[image: error]

I think that I have multiple copies of react and this causes the error.
I tried to fix it with:

```
peerDependencies: {
        react: "17.0.2"
}
```

But it didn't help.

This is my App "npm ls react"
[image: npm ls react]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple reactjs,
Try to delete reactjs in your node_modules, and run: npm install,
then restart server this will use the component in your library.

Comment: Getting the same error :\

Comment: Have you link your library to your app project ?  
in your library folder, open a terminal then:  
>sudo npm link  

>npm run compile  

In your App project folder, in a terminal:  
>npm link libraryName

Or maybe you have delete just reactjs modules, but you have to delete Material-ui modules too.

Comment: Thanks, buy I didn't use properly peerDependencies... I didn't remove it from devDependencies... It works OK if I publish and npm install the package. Now I try to figure how to make it work with npm link :)